# Android log in/sign-up sample project

Tags: android

Is there a reference sample project to implement a log in/sign-up welcome screen in Android?

I have thought about what I would need to know to do this:

- Activity layout
- Text field validation
- Text field hints
- Enabling/disabling UI elements (i.e. press login only if data has been entered)
- Async network request validating credentials
- Blocking UI waiting for login
- Forwarding to next activity based on login result
- Sign-up interlude if 1st time user
- Cancelling network login if the user wants (do not crash on call-back if user moves away from Activity)
- Saving user data, access token if available otherwise password (and encrypt it)
- Transition animations, including "access denied" feedback
- Use cached credentials if available
- Login "remember me" opt-out
- etc.

Many more bullet point to write down, but you get the idea.

I suspect, correct me if I am wrong, that many apps may have (or even start in) a login/signup screen. Probably there is a customisable Eclipse project somewhere which captures most best practices so that devs don't reinvent the wheel much?

Clearly, many apps will want to do things differently. Clearly, for some cases the above is nonesense. But.. maybe for some apps this is a reasonable "typical" login Activity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The latest version of the Android Development Tools (ADT) plugin for Eclipse has a wizard to create a new LoginActivity that can be a good starting point. It has the following features.

- Activity layout Text field validation
- Text field hints
- Enabling/disabling UI elements
- Async request validating credentials
- Blocking UI waiting for login
- Cancelling login
- etc.

It's in File -> New -> Other -> Android Activity -> LoginActivity

Answer (score 3):

1) create login.xml (activity layout) in /res/layout In this example there is an additional option for password change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Loginbutton"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login" />

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/changepassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change_Login_Id" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2) create Login.java class in /src//

```
public class Login extends Activity{
    private Button login;
    private EditText Username;
    private EditText Password;
    private CheckedTextView changeid;
    public SQLiteDatabase sampleDB;
    public String COLUMN_ID="_id";
    public String COLUMN1="username";
    public String COLUMN2="password";
    public String TABLE_NAME="Androdata";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Loginbutton);
        Username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        Password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        changeid=(CheckedTextView)findViewById(R.id.changepassword);
        sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(TABLE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        boolean x=init(TABLE_NAME);
        if(x==false)
        {
        createDB();
        insertDB();
        }
        changeid.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myintent=new Intent("android.intent.action.DATABASE");
                startActivity(myintent);
            }
        });
        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int k=check();
                if(k==1)                
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successful ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent myintent=new Intent("android.intent.action.CHOICE");
                    startActivity(myintent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Username.setText("");
                    Password.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authentication Failed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }   
            }
        });
    }
    public boolean init(String tableName)
    {
        Cursor cursor = sampleDB.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+tableName+"'", null);
        if(cursor!=null) {
            if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
                                cursor.close();
                return true;
            }
                        cursor.close();
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void insertDB() {
        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                TABLE_NAME +
                " Values ('1','Androviewer','viewer');");   
        System.out.println("Inserted data successfully....");
    }
    private void createDB() {
        sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                TABLE_NAME+ "(" + COLUMN_ID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN1
                + " text not null,"+ COLUMN2
                + " text not null);");
        System.out.println("Database created successfully....");
    }
    private int check() {
        String a=Username.getText().toString();
        String b=Password.getText().toString();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT username, password FROM " +
                TABLE_NAME +
                " where _id=1", null);

        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String orgusername = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("username"));
                    String orgpassword = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("password"));
                    if(a.equals(orgusername)&&b.equals(orgpassword))
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if u want a single time login u can use shared preferences or make a simple change in my db code .

1)u can set textfield hint in xml

android:hint="ur hint" 

2)Use Intent as i used to move forward from one activity to next.

Do u need any more
```

Comment: Why the 2 separate answers? One should be enough. ;-)